# Change cell number/date format based on value in formular

Tags: time, formatting, numbers, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with a dropdown in A1 containing "Watts" and "Split".

In A2 I woud like to automatically calculate a value based on the drop down, however, the formatting of A2 will be different depending on whether the result needs to be a number or a time.

How would I set the formatting on A2 to be a time if the resulting value is a time or a number if it is a number based on the dropdown? Ideally this would be in a formular. Is it possible to set some kind of pattern for the value in the cell and change it based on the dropdown?